# Null of linear map, range of linear map in polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: P_3(R) → P_3(R)$ be the linear transformation defined by
$T(az^3 + bz^2 + c^z + d) = (a − b)z^3 + (c − d)z.$

a) Is $z^3 + z^2 + z − 1$ in Null(T)?

Ans. No

b) Is $z^3 − z^2 + z − 1$ in Null(T)?

Ans. No

c) Is $3z^3+3z$ in range(T)?

Yes

d) Is $z^3 − z^2$ in range(T)?

No

e) Find a basis for Null(T).

f) Find a basis for range (T).

Could any one give me hints how to solve for e) and f)? Am I also right for a through d?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, note that

$$T(z^3 + z^2 + z -1 ) = (1 − 1)z^3 + (1 − (-1))z=2z\ne 0$$ and thus it doesn't belong to $\mathrm{Null}(T).$

To get $\mathrm{Null}(T)$ you have

$$T(az^3 + bz^2 + c z + d) = (a − b)z^3 + (c − d)z=0\Leftrightarrow a=b,c=d.$$ So, $$p(z)=az^3 + bz^2 + c z + d\in \mathrm{Null}(T) \Leftrightarrow p(z)=az^3 + az^2 + c z + c.$$ Thus, a basis is given by $\{z^3+z^2,z+1\}.$

To get the range, note that $z^3,z\in \mathrm{range}(T)$ and that $1,z^2\notin \mathrm{range}(T).$ So a basis is $\{z,z^3\}.$